# unable to reference another layout in baseadapter android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

i have an extended baseadapter class which i'm using for populating listview.
i want to change visibility of an element in another layout file(parent file containing listview element)  but i'm unable to find a suitable solution.
 i tried setting second inflater, executing another class and in fragment but to no avail. however click is detected fine since i'm able to log that in console

```
       convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_main, null);
        final View convertView1 = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment_1, null);
```

that wont work obviously because we could return only one view so i tried declaring another class but still same result

for some reason i'm unable to register click in mainactivity. even that could help

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                System.out.println("ArrayList Of Vssalues :");

            }

        });
```

baseadapter getview class

```
  public View getView(final int position,  View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_main, null);
        final View convertView1 = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment_1, null);

        final RelativeLayout calendartoshow = (RelativeLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.calendarlay);


        final RelativeLayout list_menu = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_menu);
        Button list_but = (Button) list_menu.findViewById(R.id.book_button);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        //getView1();

        holder.icon = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        holder.icon.setImageResource(listData[position]);
        holder.text = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textv);
        final Button holder_but = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.book_button);
        holder_but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                calendartoshow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                System.out.println("ArrayLissst Of Values :");
                //new clickclass();
               // getView1(position,convertView1,parent);

            }
        });
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.text.setText(TEXTS[position]);


    return convertView;



}
```

Comment: Use same layout i.e only one convertView . Check your visibility in the same layout by Visible and gone by using setVisiblity Method for layout item.

Comment: what do you mean. element to hide is in another xml file

Comment: no use only one xml file and then handle the visibility case

Comment: any other suggestion? your idea would replicate that included element also to number of instances of listview objects

Comment: refer this example (http://abhiandroid.com/ui/gridview)